# Use .htaccess to set 404 error document located in the same folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

So... i am trying to set the path to an error document located in the same directory as the .htaccess (located in the WEBSITE "root") like this:

```
       ErrorDocument 404 404.php
```

However instead of showing the webpage...it just writes 404.php on the screen. I can't use absolute paths like:

```
       ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Because i am not doing the website for me and i do not know the absolute path of the folder the website will be stored on...

**My question is:** Can i set relative paths in the .htaccess document rather than absolute ones? (and if yes...how?)

Comment: try with an extra dot to specify it's in the same dir:
ErrorDocument
 404 ./404.php

Comment: tried already..not working..it just displays ./404.php

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The URL-path in the argument of the ErrorDocument directive is always relative to the DocumentRoot.

However, you can work around this using the mod_rewrite module.

```
RewriteEngine on
#if requested resource isn't a file
# and isn't a directory
# then serve local error script 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule .* 404.php [L]
```

Make sure the 404.php does actually emit a 404 response header!

I haven't tested it, but this should get you started. Also note that using the ErrorDocument directive is always preferable to this, and asking where the site will reside relative to DocumentRoot would be sensible, so you'd be able to write

```
ErrorDocument 404 /path/to/my/site/404.php
```

Comment: thank you for your answer...i think i will ask where will be the site located then...

Comment: Having a comment after a `RewriteCond` on the same line will result in a 500 server error with the message `RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters`.

Answer (score 4):

While a number of directives are sensitive to relative directory while within an `.htaccess` or `<Directory>` context, `ErrorDocument` is not. Per the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#errordocument):

> URLs can begin with a slash (/) for local web-paths (relative to the
>   DocumentRoot), or be a full URL which the client can resolve.

[Source](https://serverfault.com/questions/309560/relative-path-variables-in-htaccess)

Comment: full URL are no longer supported in > PHP 5.2
You'll get multiple notice in the server logs:
[notice] cannot use a full URL in a 401 ErrorDocument directive --- ignoring!

Answer (score 3):

`ErrorDocument` paths are relative to the `DocumentRoot` server setting, which is usually found in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` This is how it looks in my file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>   <---------------- VirtualHost on port 80 is generally internet traffic
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/   <-------- this is what we're looking at
</VirtualHost>
```

Note that the `DocumentRoot` set in this file is absolute in the filesystem - `var` is in the bottom level folder `/`.

So my `.htaccess` file resides in `/var/www/myapp/.htaccess`, meaning that the `.htaccess` file exists one directory down from `DocumentRoot` (which is set to `/var/www/`). So in order to have my `ErrorDocument 404` served from `/var/www/myapp/errordocs/404.html`, I need to set, in my `.htaccess`, the following:

`ErrorDocument 404 /myapp/customErrorPages/custom_404.html`

Note that even though the `.htaccess` file resides in the `myapp` folder, I still need to include the `/myapp/` in the path, as the path is relative to the `DocumentRoot` as defined in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`

Also note that the path must start with a `/` in order for apache to read it as a path. Setting "`myapp/customErrorPages/custom_404.html`" (without the leading `/`) will result in just that string being printed instead of a document being served.

Pretty confusing if you don't have knowledge of directory paths in linux and configuration files in apache, but keep poking around you'll get it ;)