# CUSTOM ERROR 403 is not displayed, instead default error is displayed

Tags: php

I have 4 files in `htdocs/all/myproject/`

1. error404.php
2. error403.php
3. index.php
4. .htaccess

I also have one folder named ***images***

---

In my ***.htaccess*** file, I have following code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule .* error404.php [L]  

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule .* error403.php [L]
```

---

When I type
`127.0.0.1/all/myprojects/nosuchfile.php` in **URL**

xampp shows my custom built page ***error404.php*** (which is expected output)

---

But when I type
`127.0.0.1/all/myprojects/images/` 
it displays

#### Access forbidden!

> You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is either no index document or the directory is read-protected.

I dont want to use absolute path like `ErrorDocument 403 /all/myprojects/error403.php`

#### xampp does NOT shows my custom built page *error403.php*  Anyone knows, how can I achieve that ?

Comment: ErrorDocument 404 file_for_404.php
ErrorDocument 403 file_for_403.php

Comment: [This Happens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20546861/use-htaccess-to-set-404-error-document-located-in-the-same-folder) in such situations

Comment: You're only triggering the custom 403 when it's **not** a directory (`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`); I assume `all/myprojects/images/` **is** a directory without an index file and so is reverting to the standard Apache 403 error.